# Routing table explanations

Tags: routing

Recently I have been studying for the Linux Administration Certificate. I found a question regarding routing like below.

> ```
> # route
> Kernel IP routing table
> +----------------+-------------+----------------+------+------+
> |Destination     |Gateway      |Genmask         |Flags |Inface|
> +----------------+-------------+----------------+------+------+
> |192.168.180.128 |*            |255.255.255.192 |U     |eth1  |
> |192.168.40.0    |*            |255.255.255.0   |U     |eth0  |
> |192.168.0.0     |*            |255.255.0.0     |U     |eth2  |
> |Default         |192.168.40.2 |0.0.0.0         |UG    |eth0  |
> +----------------+-------------+----------------+------+------+
> ```

Answers (good ones are bolded):

> **A. Trafic to 192.168.180.180 is routed via eth1.**
> B. Trafic to 192.180.240 is routed via eth1.
> **C. Trafic to 192.168.0.42 is routed via eth2.**
> **D. Trafic to 192.168.42.42 is routed via eth2.**
> E. Trafic to 192.168.42.42 is routed via eth0.
> F. Trafic to 192.168.180.180 is routed vi eth0.

I have a basic routing knowledge, and know that general rules are:

1. scan list from top to the bottom.
2. if no match found, use default one.
3. if multiple lines matches, use the one with the longest gateway.

But I am unable to understand the marked answers. Could somebody explain

1. why 192.168.180.240 is not route via eth1
2. why 192.168.42.42 is routed via eth2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a short (and somewhat simplistic) explanation of masks is in order. Given an address, say 192.168.180.128, and a mask, say 255.255.255.192, the zero bits in the mask signify which bits can differ in the allowed addresses. 255 is all bits one, so none of the first three octets can differ. In the fourth octet, 192_10 = 1100 0000_2, the first 6 bits are zero, so only these bits can change.

With 192.168.180.240, the 7th bit also differs  (240_10 = 1111 0000_2 and 128_10 = 1000 0000_2); for that to be allowed the mask would have to be at least  255.255.255.128. So it cannot be routed through that gateway. 192.168.180.180 fits, since only the 3rd, 5th and 6th bits differ between 128 and 180.

Similarly, 192.168.42.42 would require a mask of 255.255.254.0 on 192.168.40.0. It does fit in 192.168.0.0 with a mask of 255.255.0.0, so it's routed that way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So understand, that the general rule is to: 1) convert decimal number to binary ones 2) compare octets between ip and genmask. Generally 0 bit allows some changes, so 255_10 is the strictest genamsk rule, ane 0_10 is the lowest genmask rule.

Comment: Yes, that's about it. There are some simplifications - not all numbers are valid masks. In a valid mask, if any bit is zero, all bits before it have to be zero. So 1100_2 = 12_10 is a valid mask, but 1010_2 = 10_10 is not valid. This limits the possible set of masks, so, with a bit of practice you can quickly tell whether a given address fits another address + mask without having to do the bit fiddling.